# sklearn svc.decision_function does not return result

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I am trying to use decision_function as opposed to predict. I received value of negative and above 1. I need to help to write threshold to determine anything but not 0 to get the result of the array. Thanks.[decision_function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXqjG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve. Be aware that `0` will mean that your sample will be on the decision boundary which is probably unlikely. Here is a snippet that show how to threshold the sample depending of the distance reported by `decision_function`

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
print(y.shape)
clf = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LogisticRegression())
y_pred = clf.fit(X, y).decision_function(X)

# check samples closed to zero boundaries
threshold = 1
mask_y_pred = np.any(np.abs(y_pred) <= threshold, axis=1)

non_zero_y_pred = y_pred[~mask_y_pred]
print(non_zero_y_pred.shape)
print(non_zero_y_pred)
```